# Is the SWIPT technology not the good method to increase the life of using battery?

Tags: digital-communications

Is the SWIPT( simultaneous wireless information and power transfer ) technology  not the good method to increase the life of using battery?

Because I design the Full duplex system with three device,and I found that the  number of using battery  with energy harvest vs without energy harvest is just 51vs 50.

Their differences let me feel that SWIPT is not a good method to increase the life of using battery.

Does anyone have other thinking ?

Comment: How much energy do you expect to "harvest?"  If you are running so micropower tiny thing, then you might be able to collect enough energy from the environment to do some good.  If you are trying to run your electric car using SWIPT, the results will be really poor.  How much energy does your system consume, and how much energy can your SWIPT transmit?

Comment: Whatever your numbers mean... these don't mean anything to us. Start with a simple "even if I had 100% power harvesting efficiency, how much would that be?" calculaction. Modern sensor or mobile device systems have receive powers in the nano to femtowatts. I'm really not sure how you'd expect this to make any significant difference when your transceiver realistically and even just the receiver part, use milliwatts to work with the signal. To be honest, aside from **extremely** specific use cases (define these first!!), this is a dead-end